# Matplotlib Basemap drawcounties having issues

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have looked in previous issues with other users about the Matplotlib basemap function "draw counties", but it has not resolved my issue. I still have basemap:   1.0.7-np113py35_0 with the latest python version (3.5.3-1) and matplotlib 2.0.2 version. Here is my code for a plot within the United States:

```
m = Basemap(projection='lcc',llcrnrlon=-88, llcrnrlat=28, urcrnrlon=-79,urcrnrlat=33,lat_0=31,lon_0=-83,width=5e6,height=3.5e6,resolution='i',area_thresh=1000)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawrivers(color='blue')
m.drawstates()

m.quiver(x,y,x1,y1,mag)


m.drawcounties()
```

---

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte

I have looked into the issue with making the zorder in "drawcounties" bigger (~20), but this has done nothing to fix the issue. Is the problem the incapability with each new version of python, matplotlib, and basemap or is it a different issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of the issue, as well as the complete error traceback. Running the code without the call to quiver [works just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ET2Z.png).

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same issue and was able to create a workaround by making a small change to the `shapefile.py` located in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap` directory.

On line 58 of `shapefile.py`
I edited:

`return v.decode('utf-8')` to `return v.decode('latin-1')`.

This seems to work for me.

Best of Luck!

Comment: thanks. for me, i change `return v.decode(encoding, encodingErrors)` to `return v.decode('latin-1')` and it's works,,

Comment: My file looked different than you described: so I opened /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapefile.py and replaced all instances of 'utf-8' with 'latin-1' Itt works fine now. Thank you very much.